# Windows explorer get unresponsive while application is calling web service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, web-services

I have a .Net 3.5 application that I have running as a service.  This application has a thread that calls a web service and stores that data in a SQLite database.

In development we never had any problems with this but in production the web service call takes up to 20 seconds to complete.  When the application calls the web service and is waiting for the reply windows explorer because laggy and unresponsive.  When the call returns windows explorer acts normal again until it calls the web service and waits for the reply.

The cpu usage of the process is very low and does not spike when calling the web service.  I can see the I/O hit to the hard drive when it writes to the database but that all happens in a split second and surely cannot be the cause of the slowdown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am at a loss for this problem right now.

```
Machine Specs
Windows XP SP3
Intel core i5 3.2GHz
3.5 GB RAM
```

Code

```
public void UpdateMembers()
{
    var moreMembersToUpdate = true;
    while (moreMembersToUpdate)
    {
        var response = GetMembersToUpdate();
        if (response != null)
        {
            UpdateLicense(response.licensed);
            if (response.memberResult == null || response.memberResult.recordsReturned == 0)
                break;
        }
        else
            break;
        UpdateMemberCache(response.memberResult.memberList, response.memberResult.lastUpdate,
            response.memberResult.lastMembersTransactionID);
        moreMembersToUpdate = response.memberResult.recordsLeft;
    }
}

public void UpdateLicense(bool licensed)
{
    var list = DataMapper.GetMapper().QueryForList("Select.License", null);
    if (list != null && list.Count > 0)
    {
        var isLicensed = (Boolean) list[0];
        if(isLicensed != licensed)
        {
            DataMapper.GetMapper().Update("Update.License", licensed);
        }
    }
    else
        DataMapper.GetMapper().Insert("Insert.License", licensed);
}

public StoredValueResponse GetMembersToUpdate()
{
    var token = new OperationToken
    {
        company = Settings.GetCompany(),
        storeID = Settings.GetStoreID(),
        operationID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        batchSize = 3000,
        password = Settings.GetPassword(),
        userName = Settings.GetCompany()
    };
    var lastSync = GetLastMemberCacheSync();
    return WebMethods.GetUpdatedMemberCache(token, lastSync.TransactionDetailID);
}

public MemberSyncRecord GetLastMemberCacheSync()
{

    var lastMemberSync = DataMapper.GetMapper().QueryForList("Select.LastMemberUpdate", null);
    if (lastMemberSync != null && lastMemberSync.Count > 0 && lastMemberSync[0] != null)
        return (MemberSyncRecord)lastMemberSync[0];
    var record = new MemberSyncRecord
    {
        LastMembersTransactionTime = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1),
        TransactionDetailID = 0
    };
    return record;
}

public void UpdateMemberCache(SmallMemberInfo[] members, DateTime lastSyncTime, long transactionDetailID)
{
    try
    {
        DataMapper.GetMapper().BeginTransaction();
        foreach (var member in members)
        {
            DataMapper.GetMapper().Insert("Insert.MemberInfo", member);
        }
        DataMapper.GetMapper().CommitTransaction();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        DataMapper.GetMapper().RollBackTransaction();
        throw;
    }
    UpdateMemberCacheSyncHistory(lastSyncTime, members.Length, transactionDetailID);
}
```

Comment: Code?  Is it the DB call in prod that is causing the 20 second lag?

Comment: Yes the DB call in dev takes 100ms but in prod takes 20 seconds (I'm working on optimizing this right now). I'll post some code.

Comment: If the DB is the bottleneck it might be very well due to the load on the server and table+record locks. When are you opening/closing transactions? What isolation levels are you using?

Comment: Well there are 2 databases.  1 database is connected to the web service.  This is the SQL Server database that takes 20 seconds to query but the SQLite database that the web service consumer is writing to does not take but a split second to write to.  The problem I'm having is with the web service consumer not the Server(Although the server obviously needs to tlc).

Comment: If you can not optimize the DB call, one option is to call the WCF service asynchronously (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177.aspx).  I can't comment on your threading/worker implementation as no code was posted.

Comment: It is affecting explorer in the interactive session?  Does the service involve a shell extension (explorer right-click menu) or something?  I am trying to think of how it could possibly affect explorer, which is an entirely different process.

Comment: Chris this is where I am stumped also.  The only way it could be affecting explorer I think is by hogging the resources, but it is barely using any CPU and there is no I/O from the process when explorer is lagging.

Comment: @Braden what triggers the call to the web service?

Comment: Its a back ground thread used to cache member information.  It is scheduled to run every 10minutes and continues to call the web service in a loop until there are no more members to cache.  Then it checks again in 10mins.

Comment: Found this site http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=PerformanceTuningWindows
It mentions setting the page file size to 4096 bytes as the default to help speed things up.